# Mathematica: 3D loglog plot of dataset

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a though one. I'd like to project those [three data sets](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxcwyb60hn878qy/sample_dataset.csv?dl=0) on double log scale in 3D as lines having third dimension as a time 0, 1 and 2. I tried overlaying `LogLogListPlot`s, but with no success. The problem is that each data set has a separate x coordinates. Does anybody know a neat solution to my problem?

Best,

JP

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please provide the code you used so far. Optimally,  the data (or a suitable small subset)  should be in the question as well. External data may not be permanent and is awkward to use and potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

First download the data, and look at the regular and `ListLogLog` plots,

```
data = Partition[
    Transpose[
     Rest@Import[
       "https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxcwyb60hn878qy/sample_dataset.csv?dl=1", "CSV"]], 2] // Map@Thread;

plot1 = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, All}, {0, All}}];
plot2 = ListLogLogPlot[data, Joined -> True];
{plot1, plot2}
```

[image]

Next we grab the `Line` from the plots using the usual method

```
lines = Cases[plot2, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity];
```

Here's how I went about inserting a y coordinate in the 3 lists,

```
lines = MapIndexed[Function[{list, t},
    {#1, Sequence @@ t, #2} & @@@ list], lines];
```

So now we could have our 3D log-log plot, but it wouldn't have any tick marks.  For that we'll use `` Charting`FindLogTicks ``, which seems to use a similar syntax to [`` Charting`FindTicks ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135951/9490) - but here we aren't trying to do any linear rescaling before applying the log transformation, so we give the same argument twice.  You grab the original, non-log plotrange

```
{oldXRange, oldYRange} = Charting`get2DPlotRange[plot1]
(* {{0, 0.422973}, {0, 703545.}} *)
```

And then use it when making your tick marks.  I don't care for 3D `Line` objects so I'm using `Tube` here,

```
Graphics3D[
  Thread[{ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2, 3}, Tube /@ lines}], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> True, 
  Ticks -> {
           Charting`FindLogTicks[oldXRange, oldXRange], 
           Automatic, 
           Charting`FindLogTicks[oldYRange, oldYRange]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Pick out actual data points:

```
dataset = Drop[data, 1];
```

And then:

```
Show[Graphics3D@
  Table[{ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[a]], 
    Point@Most@
      ArrayPad[
       ListLogLogPlot[
          Transpose[{dataset[[All, 2 a - 1]], dataset[[All, 2 a]]}], 
          Frame -> False][[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]][[1]], {0, 1}, a]}, {a, 
    3}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Replacing `Point@` with `Line@`

[image]