# How to add second, linearly rescaled X-axis on the top frame?

Tags: plotting

From data test, I want to plot a graph with two x axes (see the image which I have added). Two $x$ axes, one at bottom and other on top. In test data, `test[[1 ;; All, 1]]` is $x$-axis at bottom, `test[[1 ;; All, 2]]` is $y$-axis and `test[[1 ;; All, 3]]` is $x$-axis at top. With my code, second $x$-axis on top is not coming properly.

```
test={{0.875, 0.000361069, -0.137}, {0.9, -0.000429778, -0.1096},
 {0.925, -0.000102596, -0.0822}, {0.95, -0.000234415, -0.0548}, 
{0.975, -0.00066855, -0.0274},{1., -0.00114038, 0}, {1.025,   0.00278551, 0.0274}, 
{1.05, -0.00148313, 0.0548},{1.075,  0.00132836, 0.0822}, 
        {1.1, -0.000164138, 0.1096}, {1.125, -0.00036032, 0.137}} 
top = test[[All, {1, 3}]]
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{test[[1 ;; All, 1]], test[[1 ;; All, 2]]}], Frame-> True, 
        FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, top}}, 
             PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Second x axis on top is not coming properly with my code.]

As you can see, the manually specified ticks look awful with their overlapping digits.  How could I make them look like the built-in tickmarks, but with a different range?

Comment: I don't quite understand you, but maybe you want `FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, All}}`?

Comment: I want to plot a graph with two x axes (see the image which I have added). Two x axes, one at bottom and other on top.  In test data, test[[1 ;; All, 1]]  is x axis at bottom, test[[1 ;; All, 2]] is y axis and test[[1 ;; All, 3]] is x axis at top.

Comment: You need to generate custom `FrameTicks` manually or use something like: [(94726)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94726/5478)

Comment: I don't understand the question. The code you provide already does what you say you want it to do. What else do you need?

Comment: With this code, I do not get x axis on top properly.

Comment: @Raghu - if you use the function `extraAxisPlot` defined [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103382/9490), then you can enter `plot = ListLinePlot[test[[All, ;; 2]], Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}];
extraAxisPlot[plot, {-.13, .13}, {.875, .0031}]` and get [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OwRwh.png)

Comment: @Jason, I tried extraAxisPlot function, I see an error message while plotting                                                  .....Total::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Total[Automatic]. >>

Comment: @Raghu - You get this message when using  [this code](http://pastebin.com/raw/mUX6Jt02)?  What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: @JasonB. Mathematica 9.

Answer (score 3):

The method [I originally proposed in a comment](http://pastebin.com/raw/mUX6Jt02) does not work in version 9, so here is a method that does.

The usage of the `` Charting`FindTicks `` function should be clear from this example,

```
oldXRange = {Min@#, Max@#} & @ test[[All, 1]]
newXRange = {Min@#, Max@#} & @ test[[All, 3]]
(* {0.875, 1.125} *)
(* {-0.137, 0.137} *)

 ListLinePlot[test[[All, ;; 2]], Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {
   {Automatic, Automatic},
   {Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[oldXRange, newXRange]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: -Thank you very much. It is working well with Mathematica 9.

Answer (score 2):

[`Rotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html) the labels

```
test = {{0.875, 
    0.000361069, -0.137}, {0.9, -0.000429778, -0.1096}, {0.925,
    -0.000102596, -0.0822}, {0.95, -0.000234415, -0.0548}, {0.975,
    -0.00066855, -0.0274}, {1., -0.00114038, 0}, {1.025, 0.00278551, 
    0.0274}, {1.05, -0.00148313, 0.0548}, {1.075, 0.00132836, 
    0.0822}, {1.1, -0.000164138, 0.1096}, {1.125, -0.00036032, 0.137}};

top = {#[[1]], Rotate[ToString[
       NumberForm[#[[3]], {5, 4}]],
      45 Degree]} & /@ test;
```

Note that you can simplify the extraction of the data list

```
ListLinePlot[Most /@ test,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {
   {Automatic, Automatic},
   {Automatic, top}},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** If you have a large number of points then using a labeled tick for each point is impractical, as the labeled ticks will be too dense to be useful. Instead I recommend that you use [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html)

```
ListPlot[List /@ Most /@ test,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Blue,
 PlotMarkers ->
  (Tooltip[●, #[[3]]] & /@ test),
 Epilog -> Line[Most /@ test]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. I can rotate the labels only when I have less number of points. For example, if the data points are very large, then it will not be possible to label all the points of a list. Is there any way do it automatically ? like bottom x axis.